# Calling twisted's win32eventreactor.Win32Reactor() method "stop" doesn't stop reactor

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, reactor

In serial communications I'm using twisted's reactor=win32eventreactor.Win32Reactor(). 
For transport using serial port.

reactor is running in the other thread (it's serial communication thread running in help of reactor)

Before calling reactor.run() I'm creating SerialPort like this:

```
        try:
            SerialPort(protocol(self.reactor, self),
                                self.cfg.comport,
                                self.reactor,
                                baudrate=self.cfg.baudrate,
                                bytesize=bytesize,
                                parity=parity,
                                stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE,
                                xonxoff=0,
                                rtscts=0)
            self.connected = True
        except serial.SerialException, ex:
            self.log.error('Serial exception: {0}'.format(ex))
            self.connected = False

        except ValueError, ex:
            self.log.error('Serial exception: {0}'.format(ex))
            self.connected = False
        finally:
            self.comm_event.set()
```

On the creation occurs error. For example:
Serial exception: could not open port 'COM9': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

And This is okay, it should be an error. With this error protocol instance will not have transport (in case of success - it will have).

After this I'm calling reactor.run(). It's also okay, because The main thread will manage communication thread and will call reactor.stop() in case of the error (mentioned before).
But IF this error occurs before calling reactor.run() and after this calling reactor.stop() (calling from MainThread) doesn't stop reactors main loop. In case NO error occurs before calling reactor.run(), reactor.stop() calling procedure STOPS the reactor.

It looks like reactor ignoring this reactor.stop() if there is an error on transport creation.

So maybe someone have and idea why?  or maybe how to debug reactor.stop() procedure to find why reactor is not stopping?

Comment: You said a bunch of things about multithreading in the question but there's no multithreading in your example code.  The exact details of how this code is written probably makes a really big difference to the answer - so you should probably include it in the question.

Comment: I was waiting for comment like this one. Example is not possible, because it's not an easy task to rewrite on description as example. If no one was faced the problem why sometimes reactor.stop() wont work in multithreading, so I'm left alone in a field:). I think I will check self.connected flag. If it's False - reactor will not start, so I will not have to call reactor.stop() later.